Dual basis of a matrix space
I am considering the following basis $B$ of $S_2$:
$$B=\left\{\begin{pmatrix}1&0\\0&0\end{pmatrix},\begin{pmatrix}0&1\\1&0\end{pmatrix},\begin{pmatrix}0&0\\0&1\end{pmatrix}\right\}$$
Question: how can I calculate the dual basis of the space $S_2$?
Also, if I have a tensor space $T_{2,0}$, how do I find a basis of this space? I am really lost. Thanks in advance.
My reasoning is:
The dual basis of the $S_2$ space I am not asked to calculate, but I think it is necessary to find the basis of the tensor space. I understand that a tensor will be a linear application of a tensor space, so it belongs to its dual, and I also understand that $(V\otimes W)^*=V^* \otimes W^*$, that's why I want to find the dual of $S_2$, and later apply the tensor product. To find a dual basis we usually use the expression $e_i e^j= \delta^j_i$ but being a matrix I think we should use $Tr(e_i e^j)= \delta^j_i$. At no time have I uploaded this post to get an answer without thinking, I just want to know if my reasoning is valid.

Please edit your post to share any attempts/thoughts you have thus far

What definition do you know for the dual basis ?

@Grey I have just done

Your intuition with the trace is correct. In general, the elements of a dual matrix space are the linear functionals $\text{Tr}(A^\dagger-)$, where the $-$ is a placeholder for whatever matrix the functional acts on. In your case, the hermitian conjugate is redundant since all your matrices are symmetric.

I think you are a little confused over the basic definitions of dual space. So, I start from definition based on Chapter 3 of the Hoffmann's book Linear Algebra:
Definition 1 (Linear Functional): If $V$ is a vector space over the field $F$, a linear transformation $f$ from $V$ into the scalar field $F$ is also called a linear functional on $V$. If we start from scratch, this means $f$ is a function from $V$ into $F$ such that for all vectors $\alpha$ and $\beta$ in $V$ and all scalars $c$ in $F$ we have:
$$
f(c\alpha + \beta) = cf(\alpha) + f(\beta)
$$
For example, If A is an $n\times n$ matrix with entries in $F$, the trace function is a linear functional on the matrix space $F^{n \times n}$.
Definition 2 (Dual Space): If $V$ is a vector space, the collection of all linear functional on $V$ forms a vector space $L(V,F)$ that is called the dual spcae of V and denoted by $V^*$
Theorem: Let $V$ be a finite-dimensional vector space over the field $F$, and let $\beta= \{\alpha_1, \alpha_2, ..., \alpha_n\}$ be a basis for $V$. Then there is a unique dual basis $\beta^*=\{ f_1, f_2, ...,f_n\}$ for $V^*$ such that $f_i(\alpha_j)=\delta_{ij}$

Now lets go to your question:
$B$ is a basis of $S_2$, so every vector $v\in S_2$ can be written as follows:
$$ v = \lambda_{1} \left[ \begin{matrix} 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0\end{matrix} \right] + \lambda_{2} \left[ \begin{matrix} 0 & 1 \\ 1 & 0\end{matrix} \right] + \lambda_{3} \left[ \begin{matrix} 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 1\end{matrix} \right]
$$
According to the theorem, there exists a $B^*=\{f_1, f_2, f_3\}$ such that $f_i(B_j)=\delta_{ij}$.
Now if we apply $f_1$ on $v$ we have:
$$
f_1(v) = f_1(\lambda_{1} \left[ \begin{matrix} 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0\end{matrix} \right] + \lambda_{2} \left[ \begin{matrix} 0 & 1 \\ 1 & 0\end{matrix} \right] + \lambda_{3} \left[ \begin{matrix} 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 1\end{matrix} \right]) \\
$$
since $f_1$ is a linear functional we have:
$$
f_1(v) = \lambda_{1} f_1(\left[ \begin{matrix} 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0\end{matrix} \right]) + \lambda_{2} f_1(\left[ \begin{matrix} 0 & 1 \\ 1 & 0\end{matrix} \right]) + \lambda_{3} f_3(\left[ \begin{matrix} 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 1\end{matrix} \right]) = \lambda_{1} \times 1 + \lambda_{2} \times 0 + \lambda_{3} \times 0 = \lambda_1
$$
Following the same procedure for $f_2$ and $f_3$ we have:
$$
f_1(v) = \lambda_1, f_2(v)=\lambda_2, f_3(v)=\lambda_3
$$

A note about @Noctis Answer:
$$
\left[\begin{matrix} a & b \\ c & d\end{matrix}\right]
$$
This matrix exists in $S_2$ if $b=c$, otherwise it can't be written as a linear combination of elements of $B$. If you consider this note, his answer becomes the same as mine.

We have
$$e_1 = \left(\matrix{1 & 0\\ 0&0}\right) \cong \left(\matrix{1\\0\\0\\0}\right) =:w.$$
Now we can use the "canonic" isomorphism and have the dual basis $w^* = \left(\matrix{1&0&0&0}\right) $. Thus is one dual basis of $S_2$ simple $\{\phi_1,\phi_2,\phi_3\}$ with $$\phi_1\left(\matrix{a & b\\ b&d}\right) = a,$$
$$\phi_2\left(\matrix{a & b\\ b&d}\right) = b,$$ $$\phi_3\left(\matrix{a & b\\ b&d}\right) =d$$

This should be dual basis of $S_2$, because $S_2 \cong R^4$. You can prove simple, that $span{\phi_1,\phi_2,\phi_3} = S_2^$ or you can show $(R^4)^ \cong S_2$.

but $a$, $a+d$ and $d$ are the bases of the dual space? shouldn't these be a matrix or something like that? i'm a bit confused, sorry if i don't understand the concept correctly.

$\phi_2$ is most definitely incorrect. For starters, it is a linear combination of $\phi_1$ and $\phi_3$.

No problem. I also believe that there are misunderstandings because my English is a bit poor. The dual space of a vector space $V$ is defined as the functionals $f: V \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$. Therefore, the basis of a dual space also consists of functions and, in my case, of $\Phi_1, \Phi_2, \Phi_3$. They take a matrix and map it to $\mathbb{R}$. What I have written is nothing different from what @Paulina wrote, except that I calculated it specifically for your basis of $S_2$.

@TedShifrin Thank You. I have corrected it.

Better, but still slightly wrong. :)

@TedShifrin can you explain me why?

What is the value of $\phi_2$ on the second basis element?

2, but this is not an problem. A basis does not have to be normed. You can use 0.5 $\Phi_2$ instead of $\Phi_2$.

@TedShifrin or am I mistaken?

Yes, $\frac12\phi_2$ is needed. It is not a question of "normed." It is a question of the definition of the dual basis.

I think I understand it now. I was uncomfortable working with a space whose elements are matrices, because if we work with a space whose elements are vectors it is really easy to find a dual basis in a "numerical" way, but when working with matrices, there is no linear function described by some matrix that leads to scalars (I think). So we can say that the basis will be the phi functions, and since we can't find a "numerical" description for them we must say how they act on elements of the space $S_2$, right?
